# Connecting to MSSQL(jtds) with Play and Slick

Tags: sql-server, scala, playframework, jtds, slick

I have a project that's been finished for about a month that I made using Play 2.1.1, slick, and MySQL. Now I need to move this over to MSSQL and I'm having some issues.

My application compiles fine, and finds the drivers, but whenever I try to make the connection I get an `[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]` on the site, and a more detailed error in my console is:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:326) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:222) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$addLicense$1.apply(Application.scala:18) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$addLicense$1.apply(Application.scala:17) ~[na:na]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:217) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Slick error : Unknown jdbc driver found in application.conf: [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:80) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:558) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.db.slick.Config$.driver(Config.scala:21) ~[play-slick_2.10-0.3.3.jar:0.3.3]
    at play.api.db.slick.Config$.driver$lzycompute(Config.scala:7) ~[play-slick_2.10-0.3.3.jar:0.3.3]
    at play.api.db.slick.Config$.driver(Config.scala:7) ~[play-slick_2.10-0.3.3.jar:0.3.3]
    at models.License$.<init>(License.scala:38) ~[na:na]
```

The most interesting thing that I've found is this line though:

```
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Slick error : Unknown jdbc driver found in application.conf: [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]]
```

It found the driver because if I put in the wrong name it gives me an error;with this entered it does not. I have the jtds driver in my `lib` directory.

I also do connect to the db on startup

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ServerAddress/EGLC
```

Some additional info:

**application.conf**:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ServerAddress/EGLC"
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user="sa"
db.default.password="pass"
slick.default="models.*"
```

**Build.scala**:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
jdbc,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
"net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.3.1",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.3.3"
)
```

**EDIT** When I refresh a page though I get a different exception with a new set of errors that don't even mention jtds

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class models.Location$]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:326) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class models.Location$
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:222) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class models.Location$
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$locations$1$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Application.scala:47) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$locations$1$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Application.scala:46) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Secured$$anonfun$IsAuthenticated$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Auth.scala:38) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Secured$$anonfun$IsAuthenticated$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Auth.scala:38) ~[na:na]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:217) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

play-slick doesn't know the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). While Slick in general [supports SQL server](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/SQLServerDriver.scala), play-slick [makes a connection from driver class name to Slick driver](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/ce9b639a1d1643293fc3c8a5d1c2291c208514e2/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/Database.scala#L20):

```
private def driverByName : String => Option[ExtendedDriver] = Map(
   "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" -> DerbyDriver
   ,"org.h2.Driver" -> H2Driver
   ,"org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" -> HsqldbDriver
   ,"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" -> MySQLDriver
   ,"org.postgresql.Driver" -> PostgresDriver
   ,"org.sqlite.JDBC" -> SQLiteDriver
   ,"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" -> SQLServerDriver
).get(_)
```

As you can see, Microsoft's driver is supported while jTDS is not. You can now either use Microsoft's JDBC driver or modify play-slick. The change is simple. Just add the line

```
,"net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" -> SQLServerDriver
```

and it should work.

I have seen the [issue that you have raised](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/76) on the project's GitHub page. I have sent a [pull request that should resolve this issue](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/pull/77). Maybe it gets incorporated into play-slick's next version.

Comment: Thanks at least now I know what's going on. The only problem is the current version of the plugin has a different syntax and I really don't want to go and change all of my old code. I tried using the MS jdbc driver but it didn't find it when I put it in lib. Any idea why it might not find the driver?

Comment: Different syntax? Let me guess: you get compiler errors at the beginning of your database methods, at or around `implicit session =>`? Just define its type, and the rest can stay the same: `implicit session:Session =>`. Don't know about Microsoft's driver, though. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: Ah that is probably it. And the SQL server driver issue was a dumb mis-order of packages. However now it's saying it cannot connect to db using `db.default.url="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://ServerAddress/EGLC"` or `db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://ServerAddress/EGLC"` so I'm not sure what's going on... Thanks for the help though, I might just define the type and upgrade if/when the pull request is accepted.

Comment: Please read up on [how the connection URL for MS SQL Server is built](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx). Yours look both wrong.

Comment: Thanks, got it now `jdbc:sqlserver://ServerAddress;databaseName=EGLC;` I was just going off what I found in google searches.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but just trying to help whoever lands here. With Slick 3.2.3 using Microsoft SQL Server is really easy. For your SBT project following configurations needs to go to the application.conf file

```
sqlserver = {
 driver = "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile$"
 db {
  host = ${?SQLSERVER_HOST}
  port = ${?SQLSERVER_PORT}
  databaseName = ${?SQLSERVER_DB_NAME}

  url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"${sqlserver.db.host}":"${sqlserver.db.port}";databaseName="${sqlserver.db.databaseName}
  user = ${?SQLSERVER_USERNAME}
  password = ${?SQLSERVER_PASSWORD}
 }
}
```

and the following code snippet can be used to get the database instance

```
val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("sqlserver")
val db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = dbConfig.db
```

And in order to enable the MS SQL API for your FRM, the following import can be used

```
 import slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile.api._
```

I think it'll be easy to understand the setup using a working example, which is available here:
[Using Microsoft SQL Server with Scala Slick](https://www.ubertechblog.com/2018/05/using-microsoft-sql-server-with-scala-slick.html)

Answer (score 0):

I should add jtds driver as a dependency in your project:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
jdbc,
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.3.3",
"net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.3.0"
)
```

Comment: I have the jar in my lib folder.